# How to stop button text change after page load?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a two text box and Enable button.If the data is entered wrongly in the text box on clicking enable button it alerts it.If  all the data is  correct, on clicking the enable button,text must become disable .The problem is once i click enable it becomes disable for a second then the page loads it again goes to Enable.Can any one tell me what i am doing wrongly .Please provide a example if possible .Thanks in advance

Script to validate and change the button text

```
function validate
 {
var cal1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtEndDate.ClientId%>').value;
  var cal2 = document.getElementById('<%=txtStartDate.ClientId%>').value;
     var button=document.getElementById('<%=button1.ClientId %>')
      if (cal1 == '' && cal2 == '') {
            alert("Start Date and End Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;
        }
        if (cal1 == '') {
            alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;
        }
        if (cal2 == '') {
            alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;
        }

        if (cal1 != '' || cal2 != '')
         {
            var dt1 = Date.parse(cal1);
            var dt2 = Date.parse(cal2);
            if (dt1 <= dt2) {
                alert("End Date must occur after the Start date ");
                return false;
            }
        }
     //if the all the validation are correct it comes to this
        if (button.value == "Enable")
            button.value = "Disable";
        else
            button.value = "Enable";

        return true;
    }
```

button

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" OnClientClick=" return validate()" runat="server" Text="Enable" />
```

Comment: Check my provided answer, it will solve your problem..

Comment: Sounds Good that it worked for u, you can mark it as right answer so if others have same issue then they can find easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition will be `&&` in place of `||` and you pass `return false` to stop postback
After completing your validation try to `return false` and use `if - else` will save your time of `validate`

```
function validate()
 {
var cal1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtEndDate.ClientId%>').value;
var cal2 = document.getElementById('<%=txtStartDate.ClientId%>').value;
var button=document.getElementById('<%=button1.ClientId %>')

        if (cal1 == '') {
            alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;
        }
        else if (cal2 == '') {
            alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;
        }    
        else if (cal1 != '' && cal2 != '')
         {
            var dt1 = Date.parse(cal1);
            var dt2 = Date.parse(cal2);
            if (dt1 <= dt2) {
                alert("End Date must occur after the Start date ");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                  //if the all the validation are correct it comes to this
                  if (button.value == "Enable")
                      button.value = "Disable";
                  else
                     button.value = "Enable";
                }
        }         
        return false;
    }
```

and Button - `<asp:Button ID="button1" OnClientClick=" return validate();" runat="server" Text="Enable" />`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the default action of a click event of an button (`<input type="button">`) is to submit the form. You can prevent that by returning `false` from the event handler. the simplest way to do that in your case would be to ALWAYS `return false` from your validate function.

Comment: or just use `<input type="button"...>"` instead `<asp:Button ...` (because is server control and will become `<input type="submit" ....>`).

Answer (score 0):

After completing your validation try to return false

```
function validate()
 {
var cal1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtEndDate.ClientId%>').value;
var cal2 = document.getElementById('<%=txtStartDate.ClientId%>').value;
var button=document.getElementById('<%=button1.ClientId %>')

        if (cal1 == '') {
            alert("End Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;
        }
        if (cal2 == '') {
            alert("Start Date can not be left blank ");
            return false;
        }

        if (cal1 != '' || cal2 != '')
         {
            var dt1 = Date.parse(cal1);
            var dt2 = Date.parse(cal2);
            if (dt1 <= dt2) {
                alert("End Date must occur after the Start date ");
                return false;
            }
        }
     //if the all the validation are correct it comes to this
        if (button.value == "Enable")
            button.value = "Disable";
        else
            button.value = "Enable";

        return false;
    }
```